# New line in latex mathematical expression

Tags: latex

I am drawing a graph in latex where each node has a set of logical expressions. I want to separate each formula in a node with a line break. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                        thick,main node/.style={draw,minimum size=8mm}]
    
      \node[main node] (a) {$ \diamond(p \wedge \urcorner p) $};
      \node[main node] (b) [below right = of a] {$ \diamond(p \wedge \urcorner p)\ast $
       \\ $\circ \diamond(p \wedge \urcorner p) $};

    
      \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (a) edge node [right] {} (b)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want a line break between the * and the circle in node b
[image]

Comment: Please make a *compilable* [mre]. Does your node have a fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\urcorner` is not defined by default, you either need a package which provides it or define the macro
- missing `;` after the last path
- for line breaks in a node, the node needs to have a width, e.g. `text width=...`

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                        thick,main node/.style={draw,minimum size=8mm}]
    
      \node[main node] (a) {$ \diamond(p \wedge \urcorner p) $};
      \node[main node, text width=1.5cm] (b) [below right = of a] {$ \diamond(p \wedge \urcorner p)\ast $
       \\ $\circ \diamond(p \wedge \urcorner p) $};

    
      \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (a) edge node [right] {} (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, how do I add a number outside each node. I want to put number 1 next to node a and 2 next to b?

Comment: @user14545805 If you have a new question, please ask a new question